# Do a property must be indexed for associated composite indexes to be updated on put()?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a composite index (prop0 asc, prop1 asc). To verify whether it is updated even if prop0 and prop1 aren't indexed, I have made a test. The test has several requests as shown in the AppStats screenshot below.

Request 1: Composite filter query (same as Request 4).

Request 2: Creation of the same DataStore of Request 5, but with all properties unindexed.

Request 3: DataStore cleanup.

Request 4: Composite filter query.

Request 5: DataStore creation with all properties indexed.

Request 6: memcache cleanup.

[image]

Request 1 is returning no results, which is expected if the composite index is not being updated in Request 2. My question is: that's the case?

The related code is below.

```
// DataStore creation.
public ReturnCodes operate() {
    DatastoreService dataStore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

    Entity testEntity = new Entity(ENTITY_NAME, ROOT_NAME);
    Key rootKey = KeyFactory.createKey(DataStoreCreation.ENTITY_NAME, ROOT_NAME);
    setProps(testEntity, 0);
    dataStore.put(testEntity);

    for(int i = 1; i < numEntities; ++i) {
        // Chave = nome da entidade + i
        testEntity = new Entity(ENTITY_NAME, ENTITY_NAME + i, rootKey);
        setProps(testEntity, i);
        dataStore.put(testEntity);
    }

    return ReturnCodes.SUCCESS;
}

private void setProps(Entity entity, int value) {
    for(int j = 0; j < numProps; ++j) {
        if(indexed) {
            entity.setProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_PREFIX + j, value);
        }
        else {
            entity.setUnindexedProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_PREFIX + j, value);
        }
    }
}

// DataStore cleanup.
private ReturnCodes clean() {
    Key rootKey = KeyFactory.createKey(DataStoreCreation.ENTITY_NAME, DataStoreCreation.ROOT_NAME);
    DatastoreService dataStore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

    Query query = new Query(DataStoreCreation.ENTITY_NAME).setKeysOnly();
    PreparedQuery prepQuery = dataStore.prepare(query);
    Iterable<Entity> entities = prepQuery.asIterable();
    ArrayList<Key> keys = new ArrayList<Key>();

    for(Entity entity : entities) {
        keys.add(entity.getKey());
    }
    dataStore.delete(keys);

    return ReturnCodes.SUCCESS;
}

// Composite filter query.
public ReturnCodes doQuery() {
    DatastoreService dataStore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

    for(int i = 0; i < numIters; ++i) {
        Query.FilterPredicate filter0 = new Query.FilterPredicate(DataStoreCreation.PROPERTY_NAME_PREFIX + 0,
                Query.FilterOperator.NOT_EQUAL, 0);
        Query.FilterPredicate filter1 = new Query.FilterPredicate(DataStoreCreation.PROPERTY_NAME_PREFIX + 0,
                Query.FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, 0);
        CompositeFilter finalFilter = Query.CompositeFilterOperator.or(filter0, filter1);
        Query query = new Query(DataStoreCreation.ENTITY_NAME/*, key*/).setFilter(finalFilter);
        query.addProjection(new PropertyProjection(DataStoreCreation.PROPERTY_NAME_PREFIX + 0, Integer.class));
        query.addProjection(new PropertyProjection(DataStoreCreation.PROPERTY_NAME_PREFIX + 1, Integer.class));
        PreparedQuery prepQuery = dataStore.prepare(query);
        Iterable<Entity> results = prepQuery.asIterable();

        if(!results.iterator().hasNext()) {
            return ReturnCodes.ERROR;
        }

        for(Entity result : results) {
            //log.info(result.toString());
        }
    }

    return ReturnCodes.SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct -- composite indexes are not populated for a `put` if they contain a property that you have explicitly set to be unindexed in the entity.

Please see [this discussion](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4231) about supporting the feature. It also has some useful tips for workarounds.